# resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get("oauth_token") NameError: name 'fetch_response' is not defined in tweepy

Tags: python, oauth, bots, tweepy

I'm trying to make a Twitter bot and my code is getting like this:

```
from enum import auto
from logging import raiseExceptions
from cv2 import detail_AffineBasedEstimator
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import os
import json


consumer_key = os.environ.get("xxxxxxxxx")
consumer_secret = os.environ.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

payload = {"text": "LEZZZZ GOOOOO"}

request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob&x_auth_access_type=write"
oauth = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret)

try:
    fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
except ValueError:
    print(
        "There may have been an issue with the consumer_key or consumer_secret you entered."
    )


resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get("oauth_token")
resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get("oauth_token_secret")
print("Got OAuth token: %s" % resource_owner_key)



base_authorization_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
print("Vem aqui autorizar, vem: %s" % authorization_url)
verifier = input("Cole o PIN aqui: ")

acess_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
    resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
    verifier=verifier,
)
oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(acess_token_url)

access_token = oauth_tokens["oauth_token"]
access_token_secret = oauth_tokens["oauth_token_secret"]

oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=access_token,
    resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret,
)

response = oauth.post(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets",
        json = payload
)

if response.status_code != 201:
    raise Exception(
        "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(response.status_code,response.text)
    )

print ("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))

json_response = response.json()
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys = True))
```

But when I try to run it i get this error: `There may have been an issue with the consumer_key or consumer_secret you entered.`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Twitter Bot\twitter.py", line 24, in <module>
    resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get("oauth_token")
NameError: name 'fetch_response' is not detail_AffineBasedEstimator
```

I have already refreshed my keys and it's still not working!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should refresh your keys if you just posted the most recent version of them.

Then, I am not sure to understand those two lines:

```py
consumer_key = os.environ.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
consumer_secret = os.environ.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

Either you set the keys in the `environ` dict and you can retrieve them this way:

```py
consumer_key = os.environ.get("the_name_you_give_to_the_consumer_key")
consumer_secret = os.environ.get("the_name_you_give_to_the_consumer_secret")
```

Either you directly set the keys to the variables:

```py
consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

It does not make sense to mix the two.

Then, as the other answer mentioned, you are silencing an important error:

```py
try:
    fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
except ValueError:
    print(
        "There may have been an issue with the consumer_key or consumer_secret you entered."
    )
```

You are handling the error so the code continue to run after that... but without the value of fetch_response. So it obviously leads to some errors later in your code when you try to use this value.

Finally, I would strongly advise you to use some library like [Tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/index.html).

It can take care of most of the authentication process for you ([see here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/authentication.html#legged-oauth)).

And if you can't use it, you can at least read how they do this authentication [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/auth.py).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is silencing the ValueError that is happening before line 24. Let the error explode to understand it.

Because it throws the exception, your resource_owner_key is not defined.